# PHP Function doesn't work

Tags: php, html

i am trying to store the value entered in the text field using a private variable in the User class. the function name works fine in the page index.php but once i redirect to profile.php the User class can not retrieve the data. Its probably because i define a new Object in profile.php. i did this only for testing purposes. any suggestion how to fix this.

```
<?php 
session_start();
require_once 'Classes/User.php';
$user = new User();
if(isset($_POST['username'],$_POST['product'])){
$username = $_POST['username'];
$product = $_POST['product'];
if(!empty($product) && !empty($username)){
    $user->get('username');
    echo 'Success';
}
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>CSRF Protection</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <div class="product">
            <strong>Profile</strong>
            <div class='field'>
                Username: <input type='text' name='username'>
            </div>
            <input type='submit' value='Order'>
            <input type='hidden' name='product' value='1'>
        </div>
    </form>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['username'])){
    ?>
    <p>Hello <a href = 'profile.php'><?php echo $user->name();?></a>!</p>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>

<?php
class User{
private $_data;

public function get($item){
    if(isset($_POST[$item])){
        $this->_data = $_POST[$item];
    }
}

public function name(){
return $this->_data;
}
}

<?php
require_once 'Classes/User.php';
$user = new User();
echo 'Hello ' . $user->name();
?>
```

Comment: php variables are not super  global

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use session variables to pass around like that. In your index add the codes below.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $user->name();
```

and in your profile.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['username'];
```

Comment: Glad I can help. You can read more from the PHP manual if you want to get deeper understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're getting an empty value when you post the form to profile.php

In Classes/User.php

```
<?php
class User{
    private $_data;

    public function get($item){
        if(isset($_POST[$item])){
            $this->_data = $_POST[$item];
        }
    }

    public function name(){
    return $this->_data;
    }
}
```

You only take the value from the $_POST array into the private variable in the get($item) method.

In profile.php

```
<?php
require_once 'Classes/User.php';
$user = new User();
echo 'Hello ' . $user->name();
?>
```

You never call $user->set('username'), therefore $user->_data is empty.